# Token Swap from USDT (erc20) to eth

Tags: tokens, wallets

Can I swap my USDT (erc20) to ethereum with eth charges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can swap Your ERC20 USDT to ETH, if you are using ethereum chain use [Uniswap](https://uniswap.org/).

Or you can swap your USDT with ETH using [1inch](https://app.1inch.io/#/1/simple/swap/USDT/ETH)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily swap your USDT tokens to ETH in uniswap but for this your wallet need to have enough ETH to cover gas fee. If you want to swap USDT to ETH without having gas fee covered you can use 1inch (app.1inch.io) to swap USDT to ETH using fusion swap router. 1inch has fusion swap which takes no fee to sell your ERC20 token to ETH and ETH to other assets. But in that case too you have to approve USDT spend to 1inch router. So, even in 1inch you need to have enough ETH in your wallet to cover gas fee first time which is required to approve the token.